# How to Change the Attribution Line in Mail 6.0?

Tags: macos, mail.app

The current Mail attribution line reads:

> On [Date], at [Time], [Sender Name] [Sender Email Address] wrote:

I would like it to read:

> Hello, [Sender Name] -- on [Date], at [Time], you [Sender Email
>   Address] wrote:

Before upgrading to Mt. Lion and Mail 6.0, I was able to accomplish most of the above via this command line in Terminal:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :REPLY_ATTRIBUTION "\nHello, %3$@ -- On %1$@ at %2$@ (local time), you wrote:\n"' \
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Message.framework/Versions/B/Resources/English.lproj/Delayed.strings`
```

Unfortunately, when trying this in Mail 6.0, it no longer works.

If anyone has any suggestions regarding how to get this to work, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I am pleased to advise that I found the solution to my own question, as well as the solution to a few questions from others here:

There is a small utility app called Quotefix that is available here:

http://code.google.com/p/quotefixformac/

With Quotefix, you can change the attribution line to anything you'd like, and for those
asking about it, you can make the cursor appear below the quoted text in replies, and there are several other goodies that I haven't tried yet, as well. Kudos to the creators
of Quotefix for this -- it works as advertised and my attribution line is now exactly as I want it.